# I can't find POST in my blog in Google Blogger

Tags: blogger

I have tried this for a long time but is happening for the first time.

I have made a blog on Google Blogger but I can't find a PUBLISH option in my comments.

I am totally new to this.

This is my blog: https://thestudyfanatic.blogspot.com/

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Have you already look at https://support.google.com/blogger? If so, please add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Okay will do that, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go to your blog settings and do the following changes...
this will answer the problem

[image: Refer to this Image for the changes to be made]

P.S: at times it happens so that there's no PUBLISH option in an EMBEDDED COMMENTS...
all you need to do is just wait and let the blogger adjust to the settings and you are
done!